# TypeError: 'car' is an invalid keyword argument for print()

Tags: python

I don't understand the error. Here is the code,

```
car = 'mercedes'
print("Is car = 'mercedes'? I predict True.")
print(car = 'mercedes')
print("\nIs car = 'audi'? I predict False.")
print(car = 'audi')
```

When I try to run this the error is

```
TypeError: 'car' is an invalid keyword argument for print().
```

Comment: Why did you think car *was* a valid keyword argument to [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)?

Comment: are trying to do `print(car == 'mercedes')
`

Comment: The OP probably want to use the [input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function, but he doesn’t know it yet ;-)

Comment: Perhaps it needs to be pointed out that symbols without quotes are Python expressions, not human-readable strings; those need quotes around them. So `print('car = "mercedes"')` is valid Python syntax; or `x = "mercedes"; print(x)` to use a variable. The variable's name could be `car` instead of `x` but its value could be anything (e.g. `"airplane"` or `42`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to check for equality then use == instead of =

print(car **==** 'mercedes')

Comment: Thank you Virxen! that was what I needed.